# why new Date("Tue Apr 08 2008 00:00:00 GMT+0530").getMonth() is returning 3

Tags: javascript

```
new Date("Tue Apr 08 2008 00:00:00 GMT+0530").getMonth() returns 3?
```

Why does this datetime format returns -1 month. Also can any one please tell me is this UTC timestamp or GMT or ISO. I am pretty confused. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Read the documentation for Date....](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

Comment: @AndrewLohr looks like you're conflating W3 and W3schools, which many will take offense of. The two organizations are unrelated, and while W3schools can be a good resource for beginners, it has often been criticized for publishing incorrect data and taking too long to correct it after having been notified.

Comment: @AndrewLohr what is this time format is called?

Comment: @Aaron thanks for clearing that. Where would you suggest is the best place for js documentation?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is much more accurate than w3schools @AndrewLohr BTW W3Schools has nothing to do with the W3C

Comment: @AndrewLohr you can check the different ECMA specifications on [their website](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/) if you want the formal definition, otherwise I like the [Mozilla Developper Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) for their simplified and localized documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The month field is 0 indexed :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> **month**
>
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for
> January to 11 for December.

Comment: can you tell me the datetime format is it gmt or utc

Answer (score 0):

`getMonth()` is returning the right date, it's just zero indexed, so Jan = 0, Dec = 11

```
new Date("Tue Apr 08 2008 00:00:00 GMT+0530").getMonth()
```

Also, ISO formatted dates look like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
```

If the Z is present, UTC is used, otherwise you can replace the Z with +hh:mm or -hh:mm to specify an offset from UTC.

Comment: can you tell me the time format name is it gmt or utc

Answer (score -1):

Possibly because it is returning the month index from base 0.

January=0

Febuary=1

March=2

April =3

etc.

Just a guess though.

Comment: Please don't guess

Comment: Being that a lot of programming is base 0 id say the hunch was well founded and correct in hindsight. More of a strong hunch than a blind guess. Lol  but can do. @Liam